# How to pass signIn callback function parameters in nextauth properly?

Tags: typescript, next-auth

I'm trying to write a simple signIn callback function in authjs using TypeScript. I wrote it exactly as the documentation recommends. It works, but VSCode keeps giving me a typescript related error. Apparently I'm not passing the types of the callback function parameters (user, account, profile).

**This is my [...nexauth.ts]:**

```
import NextAuth from "next-auth"
import GithubProvider from "next-auth/providers/github"
import { signIn } from "next-auth/react"
import { fauna } from '../../../services/fauna'
import { query as q } from 'faunadb'


export const authOptions = {
    providers: [
        GithubProvider({
            clientId: process.env.GITHUB_ID!,
            clientSecret: process.env.GITHUB_SECRET!,
            authorization: {
                params: {
                    scope: 'read:user'
                }
            }
        }),
    ],
    callbacks: {
        async signIn({ user, account, profile }) {
            const { email } = user

            try {
                await fauna.query(
                    q.If(
                        q.Not(
                            q.Exists(
                                q.Match(
                                    q.Index('user_by_email'),
                                    q.Casefold(user.email)
                                )
                            )
                        ),
                        q.Create(
                            q.Collection('users'),
                            { data: { email } }
                        ),
                        q.Get(
                            q.Match(
                                q.Index('user_by_email'),
                                q.Casefold(user.email)
                            )
                        )
                    )
                )
                return true

            } catch {
                console.log('no permission')
                return false
            }

        }
    }
}

export default NextAuth(authOptions)
```

Also, when I hover over authOptions on the last line, I get this:

[image]

Again, I think I just need to define the type for user, email and profile. Probably I should use interface or something, but nextauth doesn't explain how to do this on their doc. Can anyone help? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Best is not to manually create needed types, but derive them.

If you cannot `import AuthOptions` you can grab them using `Parameters<T>`, which you can then destructure and grab needed type.

For example:

```js
// import { AuthOptions } from "next-auth"; // If type is exported from library just import it.

type AuthOptions = Parameters<typeof NextAuth>[0]; // Grab first parameter of function.

export const authOptions: AuthOptions = { /* ... */ }; // Type authOptions.

// Alternatively if you just need callback type

type SignInCallback = AuthOptions["callbacks"]["signIn"]; // Type for erronous callback.
```

Answer (score 0):

`Profile` is optional for the `signIn` method. By destructuring it in your list of parameters, it's no longer optional (hence the error).

Instead, don't destructure the params in the function declaration. Do it in the function body instead:

```js
async signIn(params) {
    const { user } = params;
    const email = user.email;
}
```